# Retrieve parse.com data and display in datatables

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, datatables

How can I work parse.com javascript data with  [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)?

I can't display the data retrieved from parse.com, any recommendations?

I'm not sure if this is the correct way:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var results = [];

        Parse.initialize("Application ID", "Javascript Key");
        var Score = Parse.Object.extend("Score");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Score);
        query.ascending("Date");
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];

                    var Username = object.get('Username');
                    var Game = object.get('Game');
                    var Accuracy = object.get('Accuracy');
                    var TimeUsed = object.get('TimeUsed');
                    var Date = object.get('Date');
                    var Time = object.get('Time');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

                    results.push({
                        Username: Username,
                        Game: Game,
                        Accuracy: Accuracy,
                        TimeUsed: TimeUsed,
                        Date: Date,
                        Time: Time
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: results
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add more details about what you have already tried (code samples please) and what exactly is not working, including any error messages you might see. As of now, with that few details it is unlikely anyone would be able to help straight away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is that you are trying to call the `DataTable` by passing in it a JSON file. I think your method is valid only for normal arrays. Your array, on the other hand, contains JSON. Something like this should work:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": data,// <-- your array of objects
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "Username" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
            { "mData": "Game" },
            { "mData": "Accuracy" },
            { "mData": "TimeUsed" },
            { "mData": "Date" }
        ]
  });
```

You can pass array of objects using `aaData` and then specify which column will be receiving what data.

Comment: I can't manage to display the data, do I have to input my own codes also?